# Measuring the effect of a variable that moves through another variable

Tags: regression, instrumental-variables, 2sls

## Model

Let's say that I have a regression as follows:

$$ Income_{ti} = B_0 + B_1Education_{ti} + B_2ControlA_{ti} + B_3ControlB_{ti} + u $$

Education is endogenous, and is in turn determined by:

$$ Education_{ti} = C_0 + C_1Instrument_{t-1i} + C_2Control_{ti} + C_3Control_{ti} + v $$

Which corresponds to the first stage of an Instrumental Variable (IV) approach.

## Premises

Normally, we are only interested in the effect of $Education_{ti}$. However in my situation, the $Instrument_{t-1i}$ itself is perhaps of even more interest. **For this example please assume that I am not violating any requirements of the 2SLS/IV approach (unless these are violated by design).** So, the $Instrument_{t-1i}$ is correlated with $Education_{ti}$ but is expected to have no direct effect on $Income_{ti}$.

## Questions

Now, what happens if I am not only interested in the effect of education, but I am also interested in:

A) The effect of the $Instrument_{t-1i}$ on $Education_{ti}$

If it is interesting to me how the instrument affects education, can I just get that information out of the first stage? Since the first stage is just a linear projection of the second stage, I wonder if it is as simple as that.. I could obviously simply try to estimate $Education_{ti}$ as a single equation, but I am not sure if that is still representative of the model I am trying to estimate.

B) The effect of the $Instrument_{t-1i}$ on $Income_{ti}$

I am also interested in the effect of the $Instrument_{t-1i}$ that passes through $Education_{ti}$ onto the $Income_{ti}$. Can I in order to measure this, simply replace $Education_{ti}$ in the structural equation with the $Instrument_{t-1i}$? I thought this might work because I am assuming that $Instrument_{t-1i}$ has no direct effect on $Income_{ti}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question about the first stage effect - Yes! You could look at the first stage to try to understand how the instrument is *correlated* and (if all your IV assumptions are satisfied) *causes* with education. Checking the correlation is a good thing to do anyway since you want to make sure you have a strong instrument, i.e. checking relevance ($Cov(Instrument,Educ)\neq0$). But as long as you have that the instrument, $Z$, satisfies exogeniety, so that $Z\perp v$ you can also interpret this as the first stage effect.

To answer question B - you could replace the endogenous variable with the instrument (I believe this is sometimes referred to as the reduced form) assuming all the IV assumptions are satisfied. However, I don't think you need to bother. The reason is that the IV model is essentially seeing how variation in the instrument induces a change in the outcome via the endogenous variable. So the second stage coefficient is already capturing the effect of the instrument on income.

Comment: Hi Ariel. Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer! With respect to the first question, could you perhaps explain to me why this is the case? I understand that I have to check this correlation anyway as it is a requirement for the IV. However, if I understand the procedure correctly, this works for the first stage, because in OLS the residuals are by design uncorrelated with the predicted value of the instrumented variable (so we get an unbiased estimate of the instrumented variable). I don't however completely understand why the coefficient on education should be trusted.

Comment: Because for that coefficient, it would seem to me I have to make sure that there are no omitted variables in the first stage. There might be a variable that influences Education, that I have not included, simply because it does not affect Income.

Comment: With regard to the second question. Specifically, with regard to the part that I don't need to bother. If I understand correctly, the procedure checks the effect for the variation that the IV causes in Education, but projects that on the total variation in education, not just on the variation caused by the IV. I would therefore argue that the explained variation between the IV and Education would be very different (dependent on the correlation between the two). Nevertheless, I also thought about just replacing Education with the IV, but I was not sure, do maybe have a reference for this?

Comment: Hi Tom, so the reason you can interpret this causally is that we make the assumption of instrument exogeneity which is essentially saying that our instrument is as good as random. That in turn means that we don't have to worry about OVB because the bias term which if you do out the expansion would look something like $Z'Z\mathbb{E}[Z'O]\delta$ where $O$ is the omitted variable would be 0 since $\mathbb{E}[Z'O]=0$ by exogeneity of $Z$.

Comment: For your second question, the idea of IV is to use the instrument to create exogenous variation in education which is the effect that you are really capturing. So what happens is you project the variation created by the instrument in education onto the outcome which is why that effect can be considered causal since this variation was produced exogenously. But yes, you could also just replace education given that all the iv assumptions are satisfied. Here is a good reference: https://scholar.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/jmummolo/files/iv_1_jm.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much Ariel. I should really learn to do the math, that is absolutely my weak spot. You use the words "as good as random", but that comes down to conditional independence right? Okay, so the estimate in the first stage is unbiased. Could the omission of the this omitted variable still be important for the certainty with which the size of the coefficient can be established (which would explain why adding the omitted variable would change my coefficient on Educ in the first stage)? Thank you very much for the help and reference, you are really helping me to put the dots on the i !

Comment: Of course glad to help. Yes, it is about conditional independence actually in that above comment it should be $Z'Z\mathbb{E}[Z'O|Z]\delta$. The thing is that shouldn't affect the size of the estimated coefficient.  So if it is affecting the size I would bet that maybe you don't have exogeneity in the first stage. That is actually ok in terms of getting a causal effect in the second if you do not believe there is any unobserved heterogeneity and the exclusion restriction holds but you won't be able to give the first stage a causal interpretation.

Comment: Check out the wiki page for OVB they have a useful derivation there that could help. You can see by their derivation that it shouldn't affect size: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias.